# How to access a value in this JSON object

Tags: json

I have been given a JSON object like so:

```
{ [error: User test@test.com already exists]
  length: 88,
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: 'P0001'}
```

Question: The error message seems to be an array (it is the first item wrapped in the [] brackets). **How do I get hold of that value?**

Comment: Do you have the source JSON?

Answer (score 1):

this is not valid json. try validating it at www.jsonlint.com